# Hide empty metadata field from display in CKAN

Tags: json, python-2.7, back, ckan

I want fields that are empty to be hidden from the metadata displayed in the frontend. How can I achieve this?

I tried setting

```
'validator':if_empty 'display_property':null
```

But it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: are you using ckanex-scheming ?

Comment: Yes I am using ckanext-scheming.

Comment: you can try with `output_validator`

Comment: @tino097 Please how do I use an output validator?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question. In your case you should check the https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming#display_snippet. AIK there is no option to hide the empty fields, but you will need to override the desired snippets to handle that requirement.